# Не получается запустить проект vue-cli через npm run serve

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

Настройка окружения - всегда самая сложная часть...

У меня винда 7, поэтому в соответствии с Vue-CLI я поставил версию Node 12.0.0

Установил на нее vue-cli: npm install -g @vue/cli

Версия: 5.4.0

Создал проект vue create hello-world
Попытался его запустить всеми возможными командами: npm run serve, npx vue-cli-service serve, vue-cli-service serve.
Но везде получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь запуститься через GUI UI, и получаю примерно тоже самое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот сам лог:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~preserve: hello-world@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: hello-world@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Учеба\Vue\hello-world\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: CWD: C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Учеба\Vue\hello-world
10 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
12 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: hello-world@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
14 verbose pkgid hello-world@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Учеба\Vue\hello-world
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
18 verbose node v12.0.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error hello-world@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

Comment: В самом проекте зависимости установили? `npm install`

Comment: Не знаю, я все делал по инструкции.
Если вы об этом: https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/troubleshooting.html#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-sudo-%D0%B8n%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-root

то я добавил это в файл, не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитал на гитхабе, что нужно было обновить ноду до 12.1.0